# sectionbib option for natbib doesn't work with scrreprt

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, natbib

The `natbib` package has an option `sectionbib`, that causes the bibliography to be typeset as an unnumbered section, as opposed to the default unnumbered chapter. However, when using the `scrreprt` class, this option has no effect, so the bibliography is typeset as a chapter.

I will normally use BibTeX, but to make it easier, here is an example with the standard bibliography environment -- the result is, as far as I can see, the same:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}  
\usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{numbers,square}
\begin{document}  
\chapter{A chap}  
Some text.  \citep{lamport94}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}  

\bibitem[Lamport (1994)]{lamport94}  
  Leslie Lamport,  
  \emph{\LaTeX: A Document Preparation System}.  
  Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,  
  2nd Edition,  
  1994.  

\end{thebibliography}  
\end{document}
```

The reason for wanting the bibliography typeset as a section, is that I want to have a separate bibliography for each chapter (using the `chapterbib` package), and then I'd rather have the bibliography as a section. This is for a report written by several persons, each person writing his/hers chapter.

I'm aware that it works fine with the standard report class, but is there a way to make it work with the KOMA-script report class?

Thank you for your time.

P.S My internet connection is a little shaky at the moment, so please forgive me if I'm late in replying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `thebibliography` environment inside a group and do some hacking:

```
\begingroup
\let\chapter\section
\begin{thebibliography}{9}  
...
\end{thebibliography}  
\endgroup
```