# Sectionbib, natbib and separate bibliographies

Tags: natbib

I want a bibliography after each chapter in my thesis. 
Therefore I first used:

```
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
```

But I got some errors (like: reference x on page n undefined). In the natbib package description I have read that both cannot be used, but that the sectionbib option can be used in combination with the natbib package.

So now I have:

```
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress, sectionbib]{natbib}
```

This works fine (also by making the bibliography a section in the chapter, which I love). But now I have the complete list of references after each chapter, although each chapter has its own bib file.

My MWE

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,numbers=endperiod,titlepage,headinclude,
                footinclude=false,cleardoublepage=empty,abstractoff,
                BCOR=5mm,b5paper,fontsize=11pt, american,
                ]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress, sectionbib]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\include{Chapters/Literature}
\end{document}
```

and for the chapters:

```
balaleafelj~\cite{1}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
{\footnotesize 
\bibliography{Chapters/outlookref}}
```

Comment: Could you consider using `biblatex` . It is very easy to have bibliographies by section.

Comment: I would prefer not to

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example with bibliography with Bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography) so that we can better help you.

Comment: I tried to add it (I am not sure how to get the correct lay-out)

Comment: You do still need `\usepackage{chapterbib}`, but without the `sectionbib` option. Then you need to run BibTeX separately on each included chapter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sectionbib` of `natbib` replaces the `sectionbib` option of `chapterbib`, but not the entire package.

To get a bibliography after every chapter, you still have to load `chapterbib` too:

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,numbers=endperiod,titlepage,headinclude,
                footinclude=false,cleardoublepage=empty,abstractoff,
                BCOR=5mm,b5paper,fontsize=11pt, american,
                ]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}

\begin{document}
\include{Chapters/Literature}
\end{document}
```

You do not need the `sectionbib` option because it is incompatible with `scrreprt`. A workaround can be found at [sectionbib option for natbib doesn't work with scrreprt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/sectionbib-option-for-natbib-doesnt-work-with-scrreprt):
Change your chapters to

```
balaleafelj~\cite{1}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
{\footnotesize \let\chapter\section
\bibliography{Chapters/outlookref}}
```

Remember that with `chapterbib`, you have to run `bibtex` for every chapter.