# making a chapter independent of the previous one

Tags: bibliographies, sectioning, numbering, parts

I am new to latex and preparing my thesis with latex. My thesis consists of 2 parts. Part I includes 3 chapters, while part II includes a number of papers. In part II, I would like to have each paper separate and independent of the previous one.

I do this:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% and some other packages

    \begin{document}

    \part{Part I}

    \chapter{1}
    \chapter{2}
    \chapter{3}

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}

\bibliography{MyCollection}  % the bib file of my references

\part{ }

\setcounter{chapter}{0}

\setcounter{section}{0}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\chapter*{Paper A}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Paper A}

\include{PaperA}


    \end{document}
```

Paper A already has a bib file for itself and a \bibliography in its end. Then when I compile, the bibliography of Paper A is mixed with Part I. I need it to be separate from part I.

I appreciate any help
Mohammad

Comment: A typical `\documentclass` option for a thesis could be the `report` document class. But out there, there are too many templates that could be used for theses and usually "new to latex" users like you, have selected just one they found and liked the colors or the style of the chapter headers, or whatever they found out there. So, please add more information like the `documentclass` you are using, a link to the template if any, if you are using `titlesec` package etc. Welcome to TeX.SX.

Comment: Related, for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229846/different-bibliographies-for-each-chapter-with-shared-references, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202281/multiple-bibliographies-one-for-each-chapter-with-biblatex, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419969/sectionbib-natbib-and-separate-bibliographies.